# Hiveserver2 not starting - caught exception: ZooKeeper node /hiveserver2 is not ready yet

Tags: hive, centos, cloudera, ambari, hiveserver2

I have setup a 3-node ambari cluster (3 VMs running CentOS 7), with hive just one of the services. All the other services have started, along with the hive clients on all the hosts and the hive metastore. However, starting the hiveserver2 fails.
The starting logs show the following exception:
caught exception: ZooKeeper node /hiveserver2 is not ready yet. Sleeping for 10 sec(s)
Could anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ambari home page go to **/Services/HDFS/Configs** search for **hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts** and append the hostname that Hiveserver2 installed on it.